# php simpledb nexttoken not working

Tags: php, amazon-simpledb

I have read over other post like [pagination in simpledb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623324/pagination-in-simpledb) but I am a little unclear why my code doesn't work. I am sure the problem will be obvious to someone I just cannot see it.

```
//First I perform a count based on the suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623324/pagination-in-simpledb
$result = $client->select(array('SelectExpression' => "select count(*) from mydomain Where  city='Dallas'"));

//I get back ~ 300 records when I check:$result['Items']['0']['Attributes']['0']['Value'] 

//Next I will query using count for the first 10 records so I can obtain the NextToken.
$result = $client->select(array('SelectExpression' => "select count(*) from mydomain Where city='Dallas' limit 10"));

//This works I see the 'NextToken'
$nexttoken = $result['NextToken'];  

//Now I will fire off my final query this time I would like to use the NextToken
//My goal here is to pick up starting at record 11
$result = $client->select(array('SelectExpression' => "select * from mydomain Where city='Dallas' limit 10"),array('NextToken' => $nexttoken ));
```

The query is successful but I get the first 10 records every time. I am expecting records 11-20

It looks like the NextToken is ignored. :-(

I am sure it is something silly but I just can't seem to get the NextToken to work.

Any ideas where I am messing up?

Thanks

=======================

#### Issue resolved so I wanted to share this in case someone else ran into this problem.

When using the NextToken for AWS SDK for PHP you must create a single array that contains BOTH the query and the NextToken example below

```
$params = array('SelectExpression' => "select * from mydomain WHERE City ='Dallas' LIMIT 10");
$params['NextToken'] = $result['NextToken'];  //Obtained from the count query we ran earlier
$result = $client->select($params);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: may be helpful for you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonSDB/select

Comment: Hi Ashish, thank you for the response. I had looked over that link and from what I see I am sending the NextToken correctly per my understanding of the docs.

It is so strange, it just ignores the NextToken. Its like I am not even sending it to AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved so I wanted to share this in case someone else ran into this problem.

When using the NextToken for AWS SDK for PHP you must create a single array that contains BOTH the query and the NextToken example below

```
$params = array('SelectExpression' => "select * from mydomain WHERE City ='Dallas' LIMIT 10");
$params['NextToken'] = $result['NextToken'];  //Obtained from the count query we ran earlier
$result = $client->select($params);
```